# Import installed CPLEX into Anaconda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, cplex

I want to call

```
import cplex
```

in a Jupyter notebook (Python 3) opened from Anaconda.

I have CPLEX already installed in my computer, and this is called by MATLAB, etc. However, I can not import this to Anaconda. In the [webpage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html) of CPLEX, it says I should run:

```
python setup.py install
```

but this does not install cplex in Anaconda.

Also in Anaconda Cloud [website](https://anaconda.org/IBMDecisionOptimization/cplex) it says I can just install

```
conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization cplex
```

but as I said I have CPLEX already and I don't want to install it again. How can I import cplex to a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Honestly I would recommend installing it again through Conda. It can’t be that difficult, right?

Comment: Wouldnt licensing be complicated then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are the issues your are facing?
I guess you get an import error that states that a `cplex` module cannot be found?

The folder that contains the CPLEX libraries must be listed in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Try adding that folder to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: path solved it. Interesting. For GUROBI I hadn't need a path.